Computing extensions of irreducible (g,K)-modules (with same infinitesimal characters)
Let $G$ be a real connected reductive group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and $K$ be a maximal compact subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{l}$. All irreducible admissible $(g,K)$-modules could be classified via Langlands correspondence, or parabolic induction of (limit) discrete series. Given two $(g,K)$-module $V_1, V_2$ with infinitesimal character $\chi_1, \chi_2$ of $Z(U(\mathfrak{g}))$.
Motivated by cohomology of symmetric spaces e.g. holomorphic symmetric spaces, consider extension groups $Ext^q(V_1,V_2), q \geq 0$ in the category of $(g,K)$-modules (W. Knapp, Representation Theory of Semi-simple Groups, Chapter I.1-I.5).
Question:
If $\chi_1 \not = \chi_2$, then $Ext^q(V_1, V_2)=0$ (Knapp Chatper 1, Theorem 5.3). In the case of $\chi_1=\chi_2$, do we know a computation of dimension $Ext^q$ in terms of classifications (or $K$-types)?
The case I am mostly familar is the case $V_1$ is finite dimensional ($G$ semi-simple with finite center) and $V_2$ is unitary, and then it reduces to Vogan-Zuckerman (Unitary representations with non-zero cohomology, Theorem 1.4) via $K$-types.
I do not know references where things have been even fully computed for $G=GL_2$ (J. -L. Waldspurger, Quelques propriétés arithmétiques de certaines formes automor-
phes sur GL(2), Compositio Mathematica, tome 54, n◦ (1985), PROPOSITION 1.4 gives a partial explicit answer) or $G=Sp_4$.
An interesting case is $V_1=V_2=V$, then $Ext^*(V, V)$ has an algebra structure (extension algebra).
